# SQL Query From two Table satisfying a condition

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Table 1 name: Student
Name      Department
Alex         CSE
Bob          EEE
Briyan       ME
John         CSE
James        ETE
Mike         CE

Table 2 name: Program
Department    Semester
   CSE         Summer
   CSE         Winter
   EEE         Summer
   ETE         Summer
   ME          Winter
   CE          Summer
   CE          Winter
```

What is the SQL query to print the names and the semester where each student's department have only 1 type of semester? (the server is mysql)

```
SQL Query Result should be like this:
Name     Semester
Bob       Summer
Briyan    Winter
James     Summer
```

Here, CSE and CE have both summer and winter semester. So Alex, John and Mike are not included.

I have tried this far:

```
SELECT Student.Name,
     Program.Semester
FROM Student
JOIN Program
    ON Program.Department = Student.Department
WHERE ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a In clause on a subquery whetre coubt the department with only a entry

```
  select a.Name, b.Departmnet 
  from Student a
  inner join program b on a.Department = b.Department and b.Department In (
  select Department from Program
  group by Department having count(*)=1 
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE #Student(Name NVARCHAR(50),Department NVARCHAR(50))
CREATE TABLE  #Program (Department NVARCHAR(50),Semester NVARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO #Student
SELECT 'Alex','CSE' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Bob','EEE'   UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Briyan','ME' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'John','CSE' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'James','ETE' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Mike','CE'


INSERT INTO #Program
SELECT 'CSE','Summer' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'CSE','Winter' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'EEE','Summer'UNION ALL 
SELECT 'ETE','Summer'UNION ALL 
SELECT 'ME','Winter'UNION ALL 
SELECT 'CE','Summer'UNION ALL 
SELECT 'CE','Winter'

;WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT Name ,MAX(b.Semester)semester
  FROM #Student a INNER JOIN  #Program b ON a.Department=b.Department
  group by name
  having count(distinct semester) = 1

)
SELECT * FROM CTE 

GO
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to join students with single-semester departments. So aggregate your program data by semester to get the single-semester departments. As there is exactly one semester for these departments, you can get the semester with `any_value(semester)`.

```
select s.name, d.the_semester
from student s
join
(
  select any_value(semester) as the_semester
  from program
  group by department
  having count(*) = 1
) d on d.department = s.department
order by s.name;
```

Another way would be to get all student semester combinations and the group by student to keep only single-semester students.

```
select s.name, any_value(p.semester) as the_semester
from student s
join program p on p.department = s.department
group by s.name
having count(*) = 1
order by s.name;
```

Choose whichever query you like better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation and filter in `having` clause for those names which have only one semester:

```
select s.name,
    max(p.semester) as semester
from student s
join program p
    on s.department = p.department
group by s.name
having count(distinct p.semester) = 1;
```